# Set print area in excel to a relative reference

Tags: vba, excel, printing

I want to create a loop which prints the selected range on workbook. I have a relative range selected which is stored as "Arge".

I want to set the print area as the range selected.

```
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:P37").Select
Dim Arge As Range
Set Arge = Selection             'PROBLEM
 'do loop and other code

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = ""
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Arge            'PROBLEM with Arge
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: runtime error 1004: The text you entered is not a valid refrence or defined name... this error is recieved at ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Arge

Answer (score 0):

Two things

1. Avoid the use of `.Select`. You may want to see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)
2. the `.PrintArea` takes a String (Range Address) and not the Range itself. You may want to see [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839804.aspx)

**Code**:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Arge As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Arge = ws.Range("A1:P37")

    With ws.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
        .PrintArea = Arge.Address
    End With
End Sub
```

**Note**:

If you really need to work with the `Selection` Object then ensure that it is a valid range. For example

```
'~~> Check if what the user selected is a valid range
If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
    MsgBox "Select a range first."
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set Arge = Selection
End If
```